# Enum within a class as argument

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm building a class to act as my API helper and I've nested an enum inside my class to show the response state:

```
class API {
  enum Response {
    case Success, Error, ServerError, ClientError
  }

  func load(handleResponse ((API.Response, JSON?) -> Void)) {
    // Load in data with Alamofire
    // Call handleResponse(.Success, data) at some point
  }
}
```

To use my API, I am trying to write something like the following:

```
API.load { (status: API.Response, data: JSON?) in
  ...
}
```

I'm getting an error as follows with my code above:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(API.Response, JSON?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'API'
```

It seems like the '.' in the type is a problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Surely to call `API.load...` it would have to be a class func?

Comment: There's a ":" missing after `handleResponder` before the type?

Comment: Grimxn: That was my issue. I'm actually building the API class as a singleton class, so I needed to do `API.sharedInstance.load...`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
class API {
    enum Response {
        case Success, Error, ServerError, ClientError
    }

    class func load(handleResponse: ((API.Response, JSON?) -> ())) {

    }
}


API.load { (response, json) -> () in

}
```